# how can i pass a java object to Angular 7 application at the of loading this angular app through struts

Tags: angular, jakarta-ee, struts-1

I am setting up a new angular 7 application and it gets loaded when user clicks on a link from a Java Struts application.
My requirement is i need to make some user profile/context related information available to angular app when it gets loaded. This information is available in struts and i need to pass this information to Angular application through a java Object which then can be used by Angular page.

Is thee any way to achieve this ?

This is how i am loading the angular page from struts :

```
<action
  path="/someContext/index-main"
  type="com.testAction"
  name="testForm"
  scope="request"
  input="/someContext/index-main.html"
  unknown="false"
  validate="false"
>
  <forward
    name="success"
    path="/someContext/index-main.html"
    redirect="false"
  />
```

Is there any way i could pass a java object from here to angular 7 app and use it in angular ?

Comment: How about creating REST service on your struts application and consume it from Angular 7?
ps: I am still not getting what do you mean by passing java object to angular application?

Comment: A Java *object*? Not trivially. A simple JSON endpoint? Of course.